# Grails error when running

Tags: grails, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed grails as they said on [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-grails-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) (* see below) and I have got this kind of errors when I run a groovy application:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:2.4.1
```

What could be the problem?

---

I have not seen any command of `source "/home/username/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"` kind, and the `run-app` of the test is displaying

```
Jun 24, 2014 1:39:25 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Jun 24, 2014 1:39:26 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groo| Running Grails application
Jun 24, 2014 1:39:40 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/test
```

and stops there. If I open the `http://DROPLET_IP:8080/test` page it says `Server not found` even if test is running or not. Is that the problem or is nomething that I have not installed or what?

Comment: try refreshing your dependencies. Also ensure your JAVA_HOME GRAILS_HOME are set on your system.

Comment: If I go to `http://localhost:8080/test` it says Congratulations... So It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is probably not available in the repository. You should try with another one.

I have this one on my BuildConfig: build ":tomcat:7.0.47" (my version of Grails is 2.3.7)

By the way, your tutorial is not up to date and you can install newer version with GVM.

Comment: I have installed 2.4.something

Comment: 2.4 tomcat on mine is  build ":tomcat:7.0.53"

Comment: Yes, this is the default version for Grails 2.4